# how to solve the bug in autosuggest?

Tags: javascript, json

I am using JavaScript autosuggestion for my website. The function get trigger on every key press.

Now I am facing a problem.

When I type "hosp" it will fetch all the values like "hosp" from database in the format of JSON. And I am getting the result as well in JSON [for example 5 results]. But its not showing in autosuggestion window [Only one is showing], And the crazy thing is if I gave an alert in between its works fine [all 5 are showing].

```
 //alert(req.responseText); if i remove the comment its showing all the values
 var jsondata = eval('(' + req.responseText + ')');
 for (var i=0;i<jsondata.results.length;i++)
 {
this.aSug.push(  { 'id':jsondata.results[i].id, 'value':jsondata.results[i].value, 'info':jsondata.results[i].info }  );
}
```

Also if I hit backspace key its working fine even if there is no alert!

The below function is creating the **li** elements

```
function myLoop (arr,i,ul) {           //  create a loop function
alert(arr);
var pointer = this;
setTimeout(function () {            
var output = arr[i].value;
var span = _b.DOM.cE("span", {}, output, true);
if (arr[i].info != "")
{
    var br          = _b.DOM.cE("br", {});
    span.appendChild(br);
    var smalls      = _b.DOM.cE("small", {}, arr[i].info);
    span.appendChild(smalls);
}
var a       = _b.DOM.cE("a", { href:"#" });
var tl      = _b.DOM.cE("span", {className:"tl"}, " ");
var tr      = _b.DOM.cE("span", {className:"tr"}, " ");
a.appendChild(tl);
a.appendChild(tr);
a.appendChild(span);
a.name = i+1;       
a.onclick = function () { pointer.setHighlightedValue(); return false; };
a.onmouseover = function () { pointer.setHighlight(this.name); };
var li = _b.DOM.cE(  "li", {}, a  );
ul.appendChild(li);          //  your code here
j=i+1; //  increment the counter
    if (i < arr.length) {            //  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
        myLoop(arr,j,ul);             //  ..  again which will trigger another 
    }                        //  ..  setTimeout()
},10);
}
```

Comment: Prefer `JSON.parse(req.responseText)` over `eval('(' + req.responseText + ')')`.

Comment: @DanD. I have tried this, but not working...

Comment: I didn't suggest that would fix the problem (only as that is the preferred way to do what the code does when the preferred way is possible) as the problem lies outside of the code that you have given us.